# Emoji unicode doesn't seen on push notification

Tags: android, push, emoji

I'm able to show push notifications in textview(using UTF-8 encoding) but the same emoji appears as a unicode characters in push notifications. i-e : "\ud83d\ude0a" This is the code of SMILE EMOJI which displays as unicode characters in push notification.
P.s: I'm using Firebase to send push notifications.
Is there anything else need to do in code or on server side. ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you see \ud83d\ude0a this indicates this string is literally in the message. How exactly did you send this notification? The problem is most likely there.

Comment: Yes, I can see the string. I'm using Firebase cloud message console. 
When I copy and send the emoji there is no problem it comes with char like '\ud83d' 'ude0a' but the problem is when I send the unicode, message comes with chararray like '\' 'u' 'd' '8' ... so it only shows the characters instead of emoji. How can I handle this?

Comment: How do you "send the unicode"?

Comment: Unicode : String text = "sdffsad \\uD83D\\uDE01";

Comment: @Taner Did u get any solution for this